# JavaFX Switch TextFields After Pressing Enter

Tags: java, javafx

I am running into a little problem with my code. I would like to make it so that when the ENTER key is pressed (after user inputs info into a text field) the "cursor" automatically moves to text field 2. The goal basically is to replicate the default function of TAB and also remove mouse usage.

I found this code online, but I am unsure of what to put in the //do something place

//Iam using JDK 11.0.1 && JavaFX 11.0.1 && IntelliJ IDE

```
textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
             // do something
        }
    }
});
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8zUi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you textFields named textField and textField2, then next code will do the thing

```
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
                textField2.requestFocus();
            }
        });
```